# Can MS Exchange 2010 act as an SMTP server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, email, smtp

We have a brand new Exchange 2010 based mail server and need to send e-mail from a remote website and some internal apps (like backup tools etc.).

Can Exchange 2010 act as a SMTP server or we shall we add a SMTP server like below?

http://www.vsysad.com/2012/04/setup-and-configure-smtp-server-on-windows-server-2008-r2/

Thanks.

Comment: Exchange Server 2010 IS an SMTP server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you don't need an additional SMTP server.

If your remote website is only sending mail to your users--users in a domain Exchange is authoritative for--you might have to add the IP address to the [IP Allow List](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb125225%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx).  (I'd probably do that preemptively, myself:  `Add-IPAllowListEntry -IPAddress your.web.server.ip`.)  Generally, your biggest hurdle here is Exchange thinking your web server is sending spam to your users.  I actually had to set one particular address to be [a bypassed recipient](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa995952%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) in Exchange because Exchange was very bothered by the way the web developer set up one particular form (From:  whomever filled in the form, To:  pre-filled, Subject:  Website Response (or something like that)).

If your remote website is sending mail to people who are not your users--customer@theirdomain.com--you'll need to set up another receive connector and lock it down by IP address.  I used [this handy guide](http://www.petri.co.il/authenticated-or-anonymous-smtp-relay-with-exchange-2007.htm) as an Exchange n00b, and then had to go in and tell Exchange that this wasn't spam by [adding the sender to the bypassed senders list](http://www.petri.co.il/using-exchange-2007-management-shell-configure-content-filtering-part2.htm) because Exchange (rightfully so, IMHO) thought emails with the subject line of "Invoice" containing no text and a PDF attachment looked like spam.  (Hey, I didn't write the app, I was just asked to support it.)

Good luck!

Comment: Nice, what about a local backup server inside the same domain.local? Should I need to add the machine IP somewhere?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you're asking.  Is this for some kind of backup app that sends mail from a local user to a local user?  If so, it might be fine the way it is.  If Exchange thinks it's spam, you might have to add it to allowed sender IPs and/or make the sender a bypassed sender as described above.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for an additional smtp server. How do you think exchange gets it`s mails?

Depending on your setup you may need to allow relaying for hosts.

Comment: Our setup is the most standard SBS 2011 offers... Should I add an Exchange Send connector?

Comment: Do you want to use exchange solely for relaying the mails of your apps?
Then Exchange is definitely overpowered and too much hassle. How do you handle emails?

Comment: No, it's used internally for standard employees email management. What I want to know is if I need also a SMTP server to send e-mail from the website that is hosted on a remote server.

Comment: You don't need anything else.